# Parse a word docx file to copy a specific heading paragraph into an xlsx excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Would you please help me to select the whole paragraph beneath a given heading in a word file and import its content to an excel file through VBA?
The heading is always named 'Notes' in the word file and is the heading 4 when I use the Go to command to reach it.

- I tried to use the content.find property with the word.application object but it copies the entire document.
- I also tried to reach the requested title with the GoTo method with the following paraeters: what:=wdGoToHeading, which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=4, but it is not accepted by the method and outputs an error message when compiled.

```vb
    Sub ImportWordTables()
   'Imports a table from Word document

   Dim applWord                 As Object
   Dim notes                    As String

   Dim wdDoc                    As Object
   Dim wdDocName                As String
   Dim wdFileName               As Variant
```

...

```
   Set applWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   applWord.Visible = True
   applWord.WindowState = 1

   wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc*),*.doc*", , _
   "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

   If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
   Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))

   Set wdDoc = applWord.Documents.Open(wdFileName)
```

I tried:

```
   applWord.ActiveDocument.Range.Selection.Goto what:=wdGoToHeading, which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=4
```

And:

```
With applWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "Notes"
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        With .Parent
           .Select
           .Copy
        End With

       applWord.ActiveDocument.Range.Selection.Copy
```

Thanks a lot for your help and have a nice day !

Comment: Ah. Where you use "Heading 4" I assumed a Word style, named Heading 4 and have included that in my answer. If you mean "the 4th heading in my document" then this was a false assumption and that can be removed from the proposed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with `Content.Find`...

1. When you use `Find`, remember to also use `.Execute`, otherwise, nothing will happen. It's like clicking the OK button in a dialog box, after setting the properties.
2. Generally, it's better to use a dedicated `Range` object with `Find` that can be manipulated. When `Find` is run, the range or selection on which it is executed will change to the "found" content. So `Selection.Find` would have worked for you (as long as you execute). But `ActiveDocument.Content` cannot because it can't change. That's why a dedicated `Range` object is needed.
3. Extending the found content: Word has a number of `Move` methods for ranges and selections. For this, I'd use `MoveEnd` (for details see the language reference).

The following code snippet, based on code in the question, illustrates these points.

```
Dim rngFind As Object

Set wdDoc = applWord.Documents.Open(wdFileName)
Set rngFind = wdDoc.content

With rngFind.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Notes"
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Format = True
    If .Execute Then
       rngFind.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 2
       rngFind.Copy
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, Cindy for your quick answer. I emplemented the code you suggested, which implies to integrate the Microsoft Word object library, as I guess. 
It works well, but the clipboard is empty when the macro is fully run.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry, Dim... As Object, then the Document object... I've corrected those things, now @Nix042 .

Comment: @Nix042 For debugging, put a `rngFind.Select` in there and see what's selected after running. As I mentioned in a comment to you, it was unclear to me whether "Heading 4" means a ***style*** or "the 4th heading in the document". If the latter, comment out `.style = -5`. Nothing will be found if the code searches formatting that does not exist...

Comment: Hi Cindy,
Thanks. I already made the dim of the document (wdDoc), and I also noticed this header 4 was not clear for you. It is indeed the fourth heading, I think. I can actually reach it by the command advanced find\Go To and select headings and then, typing 4 in the dialog box.
I will debug it with the select, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your help.
I achieved to get something into the clipboard with the following:

```
   Dim applWord                 As Object
   Dim rngFind                  As Word.Range

   Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.Content
   With rngFind.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "Notes"
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute
    End With

    rngFind.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 2
    rngFind.Select
    rngFind.Copy
```

There are many code lines next to this to change the layout, add some formulas, etc., but I do not put them for clarity purpose.

So, it works !

Next difficulty is with

```
   rngFind.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 2
```

In fact, the content of the 'Notes' heading in my word file is a numbering list, so it is like:

> Notes 
>   1)    first point 
>   2)    ... 
>   3)    ... 
>   4)    ...

With an undefined number of elements.

Is there a command I can use to be sure to catch the whole paragraph?
Yesterday, I tried to find a VBA command which would allow to collapse the heading, before copying it. The equivalent of right clicking next to it, 'Expand/collapse', then 'collapse heading'. I did not find anything like this, and I am not sure it is the best way to achieve what I would like.

So, if you still have bit of time to advise me, you would be warmly welcome :-)

Thanks and have a nice day !

Comment: I am still digging into this problem to find an optimal way to sort it out... and while browsing in the WdUnits enumeration, I have had the idea to insert a section break at the end of the numbering, and then use the WdSection unit.